# How to update a listview within the custom adapter?

Tags: java, android, listadapter

I have a custom adapter which extends ArrayAdapter, it includes checkboxes for each item in the list.

Within the getview itself I have the onCheckedChanged listener that deletes a item from the database if checked. However the listview does not update, and I cant call the notifyDataSetChanged() as I am not in the main class. Any ideas how?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70. Look at this look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post the code so that readers can understand your problem.

You dont have to set any listener in the class that is extending ArrayAdapter. In this class we only inflate the data to the views.

Remove the `onCheckedChanagedListener` from `Adapter` class and place it in the `ListActivity` or `Fragment` that is using this Adapter.

Comment: Thanks for that, where would I put the CheckedChangedListener in the other class? Would it be within the .onClickListener or totally seperate?

Comment: May be these tuts can help you!

1- [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listviewselection)
2- [link](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.com/2012/04/adding-checkboxes-to-custom-listview-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

Call `invalidate()` on your ListView. That makes the list to be refreshed and displayed again. *Maybe* it will solve your problem.

And I don't understand why you can't call `notifyDataSetChanged()` ?

Comment: Because I have the checkedchangedlistener within the actual custom adapter class and getView and not in the class that is using the custom adapter.

Comment: Did you try calling `invalidate()` on the listview whenever any checkbox is ticked?

Comment: I cannot, the listview is in the other class.